# bash script - create a directory using variables

Tags: bash, docker

I have a script like this -

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

volume=$(docker volume inspect volume_name | jq '.[0].Mountpoint')
echo $volume
createdir=$volume/testdir
mkdir -p ${createdir}
```

But it does not create any directory, in the volume path. `echo $volume` does print the correct path - `/var/lib/docker/volumes/volume_name/_data`

When I give `mkdir -p /var/lib/docker/volumes/volume_name/_data/testdir`. It creates it. What am I doing wrong with substituting?

Comment: please update your question with 1) the actual output from `echo $volume` and 2) the expected output from `echo $volume`

Comment: FIrst remove the `-e` and then put an `echo` before the `mkdir` and look for signs...

Comment: Also add double quotes around your variables's expansion like: `"${volume}/testdir"`, `mkdir -p "${createdir}"`, `echo "$volume"`, `volume="$(docker volume inspect volume_name | jq -r '.[0].Mountpoint')"`. Also sets the output of `jq` in raw mode with the `-r` option switch, or it will output JSON strings that cannot be used as-is in a shell: `jq -r '.[0].Mountpoint'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because your `jq` call is missing a `-r` option switch to output a raw string rather than a JSON string that is not usable as a path.

See `man jq`:

> **`--raw-output` / `-r`**:
>
> With this option, if the filter´s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output  rather  than  being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

Also, to prevent word splitting of paths, always add double quotes around variables's expansion.

I detail cases where double quotes are optional or mandatory in the code's comments; although, in doubt, adding double quotes is safe, except for special cases of:

- Explicitly desirable word splitting or globbing match of pattern.
- Variable expansion as a RegEx pattern.

Here is your code with fixes:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Expansion of sub-shell output does not need double quotes,
# because it is a simple variable assignment.
# It would be mandatory if the output was an argument to a command.
volume=$(docker volume inspect volume_name | jq -r '.[0].Mountpoint')

# Here double quotes are fancy optional but a good practice anyway.
# If not present and volume contained a globbing pattern,
# it would be expanded. It would also generate a path check access
# to the file-system. Better be safe with double quotes.
echo "$volume"

# Here double quotes are optional because it is an assignment and not
# an argument to a command.
createdir=$volume/testdir

# Here double quotes are mandatory,
# as the variable is an argument to the mkdir command.
mkdir -p -- "$createdir"
```